# Powershell - Take output file from loop, archive with 7zip, email, and then kill the original output

Tags: email, powershell, 7zip

I have a script that I have put together, for the most part the script does what I want it to do, it hit's a list of servers, looking for log files that are 25+ hours old (indicating that another script isn't doing it's job), this worked perfectly in testing(1 to 5 servers), however once I turned it loose on the 150+ servers I want to check on in this environment, the file size increased, and the email process failed due to the fact the filesize is in excess of 10mb.

So now I need a way to compress the results, I would like to use 7zip, but for some reason I just cannot wrap my head around how to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the script I have thus far.

```
# Specify where the list of servers is located.
$SL = get-content C:\Scripts\lists\AgingLogsServers.txt

# Define logfile age to report on.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddHours(-25)

# Define the current date & time.
$filedate = get-date -f "MM.dd.yy_hh.mm.ss"

$emldate = get-date -f "MM.dd.yy"

# Variable to add current date & time to saved filename.
$filename = "AgingReport_$($filedate).log"

# Files or patterns to exclude from the scan.
$excluded = @(".exe")

# Specify SMTP server
$smtpserver = "mail.yourserver.com"

# Loop to process each server in the pool.
Foreach ($Server in $SL){

$c1++ 
Write-Progress -Activity 'Looking for Logfiles in excess of 25 hours old' -Status "Processing $($c1) of $($SL.count)" -CurrentOperation $Server -PercentComplete (($c1/$SL.count) * 100)

If (Test-Path "\\$Server\logs") {$SP1 = "\\$Server\Logs"}

Else {$SP1 = "\\$Server\D-Logs"}

    Get-ChildItem  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path $SP1 -Exclude     $excluded -Include *.zip, *.7z, *.log -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Foreach-Object {write-output $_.CreationTime $server $_.fullname} | Out-file C:\Scripts\data\$filename -Append -Width 160

}

# Zip the $filename and remove the original 

# And this is where I believe a 7zip process would go to compress the result file, then I can reference that file and path in the Send-MailMessage line. 

# Email the results.
Send-MailMessage -From "Aging.Logs@yourhost.com" -To "user@yourhost.com" -Subject "Aging Logs report for $emldate" -Body "Attached is the listing of aging logs for the environment for $emldate" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Attachments C:\Scripts\data\$filename

# Give the logfile time to release from the email process. 
Start-Sleep -s 120

# Clean up the results file.
#Remove-Item C:\Scripts\data\AgingReport*
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running 7-Zip is pretty easy. The syntax is

```
7z.exe a <archive path> <file to zip path>
```

That's easy, we just need to know where 7z.exe is. So, we'll make PowerShell find that, then execute it using the call operator `&`, with those parameters (by the way, the '**a**' means that we're **a**dding a file to an archive). Then we clean up the source file, and email the archive.

```
# Zip the $filename and remove the original 

# Find 7-Zip executable
$7Zip = gci c:\Program* -include '7z.exe' -recurse -ea 4|select -first 1 -expand fullname
# Define archive name and path
$ZipFile = "C:\Scripts\data\$filename" -replace "...$","zip"
# Perform Zip
& $7Zip a "$ZipFile" "C:\Scripts\data\$filename" | Out-Null
# Remove source file
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Scripts\data\$filename"

# Email the results.
Send-MailMessage -From "Aging.Logs@yourhost.com" -To "user@yourhost.com" -Subject "Aging Logs report for $emldate" -Body "Attached is the listing of aging logs for the environment for $emldate" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Attachments $ZipFile
```

Your archive, by the way, will be the same as your log file, but with a .zip file extension instead of .log.

Answer (score 1):

@TheMadTechnician, Thank you for your very helpful post, I attempted to integrate what you gave me, but no matter how I went about it I was unable to get the desired action, I took the direction that you provided and finally was able to get it to work, here is the code that does everything that I wanted it to do, in-case anyone else is looking to accomplish the same thing.

```
<#

Script: AgingLogQuery.ps1

Author: Xander J. 

Date: 11/12/2015

Aging log query checks the logs and d-logs shares contained within a text file to see if there are any logfiles older than 25
hours old,if it finds a logfile that is older than 25 hours old it passes the server name, the full path and filename and the
files age to the AgingReport log file.

After checking all of the servers in the list, the script archives the logfile, removes the original logfile, emails the 
archive as an attachment, then waits a specified amount of time to remove the archive file. 

#>

# Specify where the list of servers is located.
$SL = get-content C:\Scripts\lists\AgingLogsServers.txt

# Define logfile age to report on.
$limit = (Get-Date).AddHours(-25)

# Define the current date & time.
$filedate = get-date -f "MM.dd.yy_hh.mm.ss"

$emldate = get-date -f "MM.dd.yy"

# Variable to add current date & time to saved filename.
$filename = "AgingReport_$($filedate).log"

# Files or patterns to exclude from the scan.
$excluded = @("*.exe*")

# Specify SMTP server
$smtpserver = "mail.email.com"

#Get script path
$ScriptPath = Split-Path -Path $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

#Get the path for 7za.exe
$zipexe = $ScriptPath + "\7za.exe"
set-alias sz $zipexe

$archive = "AgingReport_$($filedate).zip"

# Loop to process each server on the list.
Foreach ($Server in $SL){

$c1++ 
Write-Progress -Activity 'Looking for Logfiles in excess of 25 hours old' -Status "Processing $($c1) of $($SL.count)" -CurrentOperation $Server -PercentComplete (($c1/$SL.count) * 100)

If (Test-Path "\\$Server\logs") {$SP1 = "\\$Server\Logs"}

Else {$SP1 = "\\$Server\D-Logs"}

    Get-ChildItem  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path $SP1 -Exclude $excluded -Include *.zip, *.7z, *.log -Recurse | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Foreach-Object {write-output $_.CreationTime $server $_.fullname} | Out-file C:\Scripts\data\$filename -Append -Width 160

}


# Zip the $filename
& sz a -mmt -tzip c:\Scripts\Data\$archive C:\Scripts\data\AgingReport*.log -stl

# Clean up the results file.
Remove-Item -Force C:\Scripts\data\$filename

# Email the results.
Send-MailMessage -From "Aging.Logs@echopass.com" -To "user@email.com" -Subject "Aging Logs report for $emldate" -Body "Attached is the listing of aging logs for the environment for $emldate" -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Attachments C:\Scripts\data\$archive

# Give the logfile time to release from the email process. 
Start-Sleep -s 15

# Clean up the results file.
Remove-Item -Force C:\Scripts\data\$archive
```